# ERROR ITMS-9000: Invalid Image Path - referenced under 'CFBundleIcons' appicon-260x60

Tags: ios, icons, xcode6, app-store-connect

I'm trying to release my first app using XCode 6.1, but facing an Error message telling me:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Image Path - No Image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons' : 'AppIcon-260x60'"

Note it is pointing to an icon which is 260x60 px, this really gets me confused. I am using Assets Catalogs, and can't find anywhere where this icon fits.

May anyone please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Look at your Info,plist for `CFBundleIcons`.

Comment: I don't have any CFBundleIcons inside info.plist .
There was actualy a line named CFBundleIcons~ipad  with 0 Item, so I deleted it, thinking that this was what was causing a conflict.
However if I do need to have that CFBundleIcons line within plist.info ,kindly advice me about how to set it properly.
Best,

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue. Please create new icon asset using "App icon and images lunch" property and add all icon again in that asset.

It will work.